# Where can I find the Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I am trying to write a WPF application and I require a function in the Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging namespace.  I have tried adding a reference in the Reference Manager of Visual Studio.  I have looked in Nuget package manager.  I just can't seem to find it anywhere.  Can someone guide me, please?

Comment: You're not just looking for `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to load svg files without converting to xaml via third-party libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the Windows.UI namespaces are only valid for UWP apps and not WPF apps.

Comment: Seems right. The page for it is under UWP\API Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you're doing exactly but you can now use uwp in wpf.
There are some wrapped controls and there's "xaml islands".

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/11/02/xaml-islands-a-deep-dive-part-1/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls